# How can I apply multiplier to all my constraints created on nib files?

Tags: ios, objective-c, constraints, xib, ios-autolayout

I've pretty much finished my project, only to realize fonts and spaces in between look weird in iPhone 6Plus.

I've created all my constraints to drag and drop on XIB files. My colleague added these codes on a global function so I can apply the multipliers:

```
- (float)constraintScale {
    if (IS_STANDARD_IPHONE_6_PLUS) {
    return 1.29;
}
return 1.0;}

- (float)textScale {
    if (IS_STANDARD_IPHONE_6_PLUS) 
  {
    return 1.16;
  }
return 1.0; }
```

My problem is now having to drag each (more than 100) constraints into my code and applying each with these multiplier and scale. Is there a more convenient way to add multipliers to my XIB files? I've thought about subclassing but that will probably take the same amount of time?

Answer (score 1):

```
self.view.constraints
```

will give you all the constraints on the view.

```
for(NSLayoutConstraint *c in self.view.constraints)
{
     c.multiplier = [self constraintScale];
}
```

probably work. Hope it helps.

edit:
sorry for readonly issue. another way to get rid of this problem may be;

```
NSMutableArray *constraintsNew = [NSMutableArray new];
for (NSLayoutConstraint *c in self.view.constraints)
{
    NSLayoutConstraint *newC = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:c.firstItem
                                                            attribute:c.firstAttribute
                                                            relatedBy:c.relation
                                                               toItem:c.secondItem
                                                            attribute:c.secondAttribute
                                                           multiplier:[self constraintScale]
                                                             constant:c.constant];
    [constraintsNew addObject:newC];
}

[self.view removeConstraints:self.view.constraints];
[self.view addConstraints:constraintsNew];
```

Comment: sorry for that. replacing constraints may be another way. have a nice day